# Setting Plotly Heatmap Range

Tags: python, range, plotly, heatmap

I am trying to plot an animation of heatmaps with `plotly` and I want them to have the same legend range. Is there an easy way to do that, similar to setting `vmin/vmax` range in `Seaborn`?

```
# this works in seaborn
ax = sns.heatmap(data[0], vmin = vmin, vmax = vmax) 

# my plotly code
figure = {
       'data': [trace],
       'layout': {},
       'frames': frames
     }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the trace (in this case is not shown but I assume you're using `graph_objs.Heatmap` or `graph_objs.Heatmapgl`) you should be able to set the parameters `zmin` and `zmax`, that have the same behavior as `vmin` and `vmax`.

Comment: Great. This works also with Plotly Express `fig = px.imshow(df, title='Foo', zmin=0, zmax=50)`

Comment: This also works on figure factory heatmaps, such as `ff.create_annotated_heatmap(zmin=0, zmax=1, zauto=False, ...)`